# .Net logs for assembly load error?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I am trying to modify an application and replace the application into my machine, I have the source code. But every time I put my new binaries into the machine the DLL can't be loaded. I am quite sure the problem is the signing signature, but as there is several DLLs I can't know which one has problems. So I am wondering if an assembly is loaded with error, is there any logs I can analyze to get the root of the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but after I use that I got nothing in the log.

Comment: You need to enable logging in the Registry. It's explained on the same web page, under the Community Content section, down at the bottom.